# Trouble using LaTeX font in TeXWorks

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use the following code to write in [Baskervald X](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baskervaldx/)

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx} % lining figures
\usepackage[bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Baskervald X}
\subsection*{\textbackslash normalfont}
\normalfont\normalfont
\input catalogue
\subsection*{\textbackslash itshape}
\normalfont\itshape
\input catalogue
\subsection*{\textbackslash bfseries}
\normalfont\bfseries
\input catalogue
\subsection*{\textbackslash bfseries\textbackslash itshape}
\normalfont\bfseries\itshape
\input catalogue
\newpage
\normalfont\normalfont
\input fonttable
\section{Math}
\normalfont
\[
\mathbf{B}(P)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf{I}\times\hat{r}'}{r'^2}dl    = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\,I\!\int\frac{d\boldsymbol{l}\times\hat{r}'}{r'^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

But it is showing me the following error message,

```
! I can't find file `catalogue'.
l.20 \input catalogue

Please type another input file name:
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you don't have a `catalogue.tex` file, what else TeX should do?

Comment: @egreg: What is `catalogue.tex` file?

Comment: *You* have `\input catalogue` in your document. Where did you find that code?

Comment: @egreg: I clicked on the link [Baskervald X](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baskervaldx/) and tried to open the `.tex` file in TeXWorks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got is the LaTeX source for the example, but the files `catalogue.tex` and `fonttable.tex` are not included in the normal TeX distributions.

All you need for having your document use Baskervaldx are the lines

```
\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx} % lining figures
\usepackage[bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}
```

that you add to your document preamble, for instance

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lf]{Baskervaldx} % lining figures
\usepackage[bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % math italic letters from Nimbus Roman
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}

% other packages or commands

\begin{document}

My document using Baskervaldx

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got similar problem while trying to use several other fonts. The [Calligra](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/) font may be taken as an example. Is there any general procedure to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @user170039 Yes, making a precise question on this site. ;-)